# Remove permalink from images when inserting into post

Tags: posts, permalinks, images, visual-editor

In previous versions of WP, we were able to remove permalink from images while we were inserting images into post.

But now there is no obvious option to do so. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert an image to the post you see `Add media` modal dialog. It has a field named `Link URL` with three buttons underneath, including `None` to remove the link.

*Screenshot*:

[image]

Comment: While the answer is basically correct, that screenshot is from pre-3.5. In WordPress 3.5, the option is called "Link To" and it is a dropdown box, underneath the Alignment dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

When [inserting images](https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages) into posts and pages in WP 4.4, change the **Link To** under [**ATTTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages#Step_5_.E2.80.93_Attachment_Display_Settings) to *None*.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin to add an option to use an external link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/screenshots/